# How to know which is more advatageous with assigning same value to different attributes in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Between the two in python which will be faster and advatageous

```
a = b = c = d = 1
```

and

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = 1
d = 1
```

Comment: If you are looking for a high time efficiency the answer from sun qingyao is the most adequate. However, if you are looking for a more readable and _pythonic_ code, I think that the second option is better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply run a test:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> min(timeit.repeat('a = b = c = d = 1', number=10000000))
0.4885740280151367
>>> min(timeit.repeat('a = 1; b = 1; c = 1; d = 1', number=10000000))
0.6283371448516846
```

Also note:

```
>>> min(timeit.repeat('a, b, c, d = 1, 1, 1, 1', number=10000000))
0.4040501117706299
```